# Edittext with setOnTouchListener

Tags: android, android-edittext

how can i fix this warnings found

```
et=edittext
```

[image]

***the error that displays***

Custom view `EditText` has setOnTouchListener called on it but does not override performClick less... (Ctrl+F1) 
If a View that overrides onTouchEvent or uses an OnTouchListener does not also implement performClick and call it when clicks are detected, the View may not handle accessibility actions properly. Logic handling the click actions should ideally be placed in View#performClick as some accessibility services invoke performClick when a click action should occur.

Comment: thinks .I do not use a custom view that extends EditText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For your code its better to just override `onClick` instead of** `setOnTouchListener`

move your code from `onTouch` to `onClick` then remove all `setOnTouchListener` methods

```
etx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // here etx is clicked add your code here

        }

 });
```

**you can also use focus instead of click:**

```
etx.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            // etx got focus (is selected)
        } else {
            // etx exited from focus (deselected)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thinks. how can i use this method?

Comment: just move your code from `onTouch` to `onClick` and remove `setOnTouchListener` methods

Comment: thiks.  I use setOnTouchListener to know which editext is selected

Comment: when `etx.setOnClickListener` is called click is on `etx`

Comment: ok thus when click is performed you know which edtText is clicked on

Comment: when etx is selected I want to insert a value for example if et1 is selected I want to insert 1,2, ... 9

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //You code on click
    } 
});
```